# Adding Curly Braces on Array of String PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Im looking for the way to add curly braces {} on my Array of string :

```
print_r(json_encode($temp));

temp = [{"Red":1,"Blue":2,"Green":2}]
```

Im creating that values with :

```
$query_final = (my query);
$query = $this->db->query($query_final)->result_array();
$res = array_count_values(array_column($query, 'status'));
array_push($temp, $res);
print_r(json_encode($temp));
```

> become:

```
print_r(json_encode($temp));

temp = [{"Red": "1"},{"Idle":"2"},{"Overload":"2"}]
```

So far i've tried to use implode :

```
$temp = implode(",", $temp);
print_r(json_encode($temp));
```

but it just giving the error, is there any way to do the right thing ?

Comment: How do you create the values in `$temp`?

Comment: are you expecting an array with that json ?

Comment: yes sir, i expecting an array with that json @PHPnoob

Comment: You need to improve your question. What is the actual source? `var_export($temp);` What is the expected result? Read also [ask]

Comment: please do a `var_export(json_decode('[{"Red": "1"},{"Idle":"2"},{"Overload":"2"}]'))` and examine the output. You'll know then what you need for input to recreate it.

Comment: i've added my actual source sir @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: Let's be more concrete: Your current data is `[{"Red":1,"Blue":2,"Green":2}]`. For some irrational reason, whyever, you want instead `[{"Red": "1"},{"Blue":"2"},{"Green":"2"}]`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_count_values()` returns a list of the values and the number of times they occur, so just using `array_push()` will add this entire array as 1 item and give you the results your getting.

Instead, you can add the results one at a time to the `$temp` array and get the results your after...

```
$temp = [];
$res = array_count_values(array_column($query, 'status'));
foreach ( $res as $key=>$item )   {
    $temp[] = [$key => $item];
}
print_r(json_encode($temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode your json with `json_decode($temp, true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode on an array to get a JSON. Like so:

```
$temp = ['Red' => 1,
'Blue' => 2,
'Green' => 2
];

print_r(json_encode($temp)); // {"Red":1,"Blue":2,"Green":2}
```

Comment: Your `print_r()` comment result is wrong given your `$temp`.